# Create a GUI that allows user to enter prefix expressions and displays result in GUI

Tags: java, user-interface

```
import java.util.*;

public class PrefixExpression
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("This program evaluates prefix expressions ");
        System.out.println("for operators *, /, %, +, and - ");
        System.out.print("expression? ");
        System.out.println("value = " + evaluate(keyboard));
    }

    // pre : input contains a legal prefix expression
    // post: expression is consumed and the result is returned
    public static double evaluate(Scanner input)
    {
        if (input.hasNextDouble())
        {
            return input.nextDouble();
        }
        else
        {
            String operator = input.next();
            double operand1 = evaluate(input);
            double operand2 = evaluate(input);
            return evaluate(operator, operand1, operand2);
        }
    }

    // pre : operator is one of *, /, %, + or -
    // post: returns the result of applying the given operator to
    //       the given operands
    public static double evaluate(String operator, double operand1, double operand2)
    {
        if (operator.equals("*"))
        {
            return operand1 * operand2;
        }
        else if (operator.equals("/"))
        {
            return operand1 / operand2;
        }
        else if (operator.equals("%"))
        {
            return operand1 % operand2;
        }
        else if (operator.equals("+"))
        {
            return operand1 + operand2;
        }
        else if (operator.equals("-"))
        {
            return operand1 - operand2;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("illegal operator " + operator);
        }
    }
}
```

I need help creating a GUI for this prefix expression program. The GUI allows the user to enter prefix expressions and the results are displayed in the GUI.

Example:

Enter Expression: * + 16 4 + 3 1

Result: 80

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you need help with specifically? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Is this homework? If so you may want to tag it as such. It doesn't help you to learn if you are handed the answer and people here generally don't like to give direct homework answers.

Comment: @AdamP Hi Adam P, yes, this is homework. I'm new to programming and the textbook doesn't provide me all the information I need to do the projects. Just trying to get some help. For future projects, where can I go to get the help I need? Thanks.